# Whitelist a script for Internet Access

Tags: linux, windows, networking, server, firewall

We've a windows server and a linux server. There is no internet on both servers. Now, we need to deploy a python script on these servers which will make an http get request to an outside network url. So, I would need internet for that. But we can't enable internet for all applications. Is there a way we can enable internet only for this particular script?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know well Linux platform, but you could allow the program to make outgoing requests with the command line, from python like so:

```py
import sys
import os

def allow_outbound_connections(program_path):
    """
    Allow program outbound connections.
    """
    if "win" in sys.platform:
        command = f'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="{program_path}" '\
              'dir=out action=block program= "{os.path.basename(program_path}"'\
              ' enable=yes profile=any'
    if "linux" in sys.platform:
        # *Add a similar command in Linux*

    with os.popen(command) as stream:
        return stream.read()


def main():
    # First allow this program to make outbound connections.
    output = allow_outbound_connections(__file__)
    # (Eventually you could handle the output)

    # Now make request to an outside network url.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I got it working by adding proxy settings in .condarc file.